# Specific Algorithm for determining all multiple of a number

Tags: algorithm

I am trying to determine an algorithm for a project i am doing. the goal is to get all number combination sequence where each adjacent number's maximum are multiples of each other. The numbers and sequence length are inputs.

example : 
if I give an input of **sequence length 3** and a **max number 5** i should get an output like this one.

```
[ 1, 1, 1 ]
[ 1, 1, 2 ]
[ 1, 1, 3 ]
[ 1, 1, 4 ]
[ 1, 2, 4 ]
[ 1, 3, 3 ]
[ 1, 4, 4 ]
[ 2, 2, 2 ]
[ 2, 2, 4 ]
[ 2, 4, 4 ]
[ 3, 3, 3 ]
[ 4, 4, 4 ]
```

in all sequences, each number is a multiple of its previous neighbour, while all numbers are less than 5 which is the maximum given as input.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried a sequential algorithm that didn't get me anywhere i wanted to, i am trying to implement a tree where the root is a unique initial number of each sequence, so in the example, we get 4 trees.

Answer (score 1):

You can use backtracking to get all the sequences you want.

Backtracking is really similar to DFS. You can make recursive function which uses parameter {how many numbers you put in sequence yet}, and you call recursive function after putting proper value in sequence(parameter + 1).
At the end of function, you have to clear the number you put in sequence.
Also you will kill the function if sequence is full.

Comment: Can you explain more with some code or pseudocode ?

Answer (score 0):

```
int seq[105];

void f(int idx) {
    if(idx == length) print();
    for(int i=1;1;i++) {
        if(i*seq[idx-1] > max_number) break;
        seq[idx]=i*seq[idx-1];
        f(idx+1);
        seq[idx]=0;
    }
```

Comment: if you can post the full code and preferably edit your own answer,